# how to optimize and combine two SQL queries

Tags: sql

I have two SQL queries. First for these pl - 'IQ', 'SM', 'T2' and secondly for 
pl ='AT','VV','CM'. I receive the following information -

[image]

Is there any option to optimize these two queries and combine them in one? The information in CASE statement is repeatable, only the pl differs.

First query:

```
/* Formatted on 10.7.2016 1:23:06  (QP5 v5.163.1008.3004) */
SELECT DISTINCT
       pl,
       SUM (
          CASE
             WHEN pl IN ('IQ', 'SM', 'T2')
             THEN
                CASE
                   WHEN time LIKE '201601%'
                   THEN
                      ( (charge / POWER (10, decimals)) * 1.27131)
                   WHEN time LIKE '201602%'
                   THEN
                      ( (charge / POWER (10, decimals)) * 1.27609)
                   WHEN time LIKE '201603%'
                   THEN
                      ( (charge / POWER (10, decimals)) * 1.263019)
                   WHEN time LIKE '201604%'
                   THEN
                      ( (charge / POWER (10, decimals)) * 1.251591)
                   WHEN time LIKE '201605%'
                   THEN
                      ( (charge / POWER (10, decimals)) * 1.248002)
                   WHEN time LIKE '201606%'
                   THEN
                      ( (charge / POWER (10, decimals)) * 1.252972)
                   WHEN time LIKE '201607%'
                   THEN
                      ( (charge / POWER (10, decimals)) * 1.248432)
                   WHEN time LIKE '201608%'
                   THEN
                      ( (charge / POWER (10, decimals)) * 1.25790)
                   WHEN time LIKE '201609%'
                   THEN
                      ( (charge / POWER (10, decimals)) * 1.240378)
                   ELSE
                      0
                END
             ELSE
                0
          END)
       OVER ()
          AS charge
  FROM ch
 WHERE     TYPE = 'MO'
       AND pl IN ('IQ', 'SM', 'T2')
       AND time BETWEEN '20160101000000' AND '20160930235959'
```

Second query:

```
/* Formatted on 10.7.2016 1:36:11  (QP5 v5.163.1008.3004) */
SELECT DISTINCT
   pl,
   SUM (
      CASE
         WHEN pl IN ('AT', 'VV', 'CM')
         THEN
            CASE
               WHEN time LIKE '201601%'
               THEN
                  ( (charge / POWER (10, decimals)) * 1.27131)
               WHEN time LIKE '201602%'
               THEN
                  ( (charge / POWER (10, decimals)) * 1.27609)
               WHEN time LIKE '201603%'
               THEN
                  ( (charge / POWER (10, decimals)) * 1.263019)
               WHEN time LIKE '201604%'
               THEN
                  ( (charge / POWER (10, decimals)) * 1.251591)
               WHEN time LIKE '201605%'
               THEN
                  ( (charge / POWER (10, decimals)) * 1.248002)
               WHEN time LIKE '201606%'
               THEN
                  ( (charge / POWER (10, decimals)) * 1.252972)
               WHEN time LIKE '201607%'
               THEN
                  ( (charge / POWER (10, decimals)) * 1.248432)
               WHEN time LIKE '201608%'
               THEN
                  ( (charge / POWER (10, decimals)) * 1.25790)
               WHEN time LIKE '201609%'
               THEN
                  ( (charge / POWER (10, decimals)) * 1.240378)
               ELSE
                  0
            END
         ELSE
            0
      END)
   OVER ()
      AS charge
FROM ch
WHERE     TYPE = 'MO'
   AND pl IN ('AT', 'VV', 'CM')
   AND time BETWEEN '20160101000000' AND '20160930235959'
```

Thanks for your help you in advance

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag your question with the database you are actually using.

Comment: Is there any particular reason to use a *text* column for storing {date,time,timestamp} stuff, and calling it `time` ?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want `union all`:

```
with q1 as (
      <first query here>
     ),
     q2 as (
      <second query here>
     )
select q1.*
from q1
union all
select q2.*
from q2;
```

Comment: Is the CTE necessary? The table-values can be inlined as subqueries.

Comment: @Dai . . . The CTE is not necessary.  Subqueries could be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

You and stick UNION ALL in between the 2 queries to combine them. In order to help you with optimizing, I need more info, e.g. table structure, indexes...etc.

Answer (score 0):

if your query has same field names in select statement, then you can use "UNION".
simple e.g. is,

```
select id,name from table1 where condition
Union
select id,name from table2 where condition
```

this will give you combine result of both queries.

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned, it is queer that you seem to store your datetimes as strings. But anyway:

Your queries select the same type and time range from the table, only that one considers one set of PLs and the other another. They even use the same formulas in your select clause. So this can be easily combined

```
with factors as
(
  select '201601%' as pattern, 1.27131 as factor
  union all
  select '201602%' as pattern, 1.27609 as factor
  union all
  select '201603%' as pattern, 1.263019 as factor
  union all
  select '201604%' as pattern, 1.251591 as factor
  union all
  select '201605%' as pattern, 1.248002 as factor
  union all
  select '201606%' as pattern, 1.252972 as factor
  union all
  select '201607%' as pattern, 1.248432 as factor
  union all
  select '201608%' as pattern, 1.25790 as factor
  union all
  select '201609%' as pattern, 1.240378 as factor
)
select pl, sum(charge) over 
            (partition by case when pl in ('IQ', 'SM', 'T2') then 1 else 2 end) as charge
from
(
  select
    pl,
    sum(case when f.factor is null then 0 
             else ch.charge / power(10, ch.decimals) * f.factor end) as charge
  from ch
  left join factors f on ch.time like f.pattern
  where type = 'MO'
  and time BETWEEN '20160101000000' AND '20160930235959'
  and pl in ('IQ', 'SM', 'T2', 'AT', 'VV', 'CM')
  group by pl
) pls;
```

You can even do this without the subquery. Choose whatever you find more readable.

```
select
  pl,
  sum
  (
    sum(case when f.factor is null then 0 
             else ch.charge / power(10, ch.decimals) * f.factor end)
  ) over (partition by case when pl in ('IQ', 'SM', 'T2') then 1 else 2 end) as charge
from ch
left join factors f on ch.time like f.pattern
where type = 'MO'
and time BETWEEN '20160101000000' AND '20160930235959'
and pl in ('IQ', 'SM', 'T2', 'AT', 'VV', 'CM')
group by pl;
```

You may want to create a table for the factors, so you would get rid of the with clause.